# How to work with SQLite (CRUD) in a Quasar project?

Tags: sqlite, vue.js, knex.js, quasar-framework

On a Quasar v2 project (with Vue 3 and Composition API) I need to use an already populated SQLite database. I'm not able to import data from inside a Vue component directly.

Maybe it has to be initialized from somewhere else (boot file or electron-main)? How can I make CRUD operations from a Vue component using Quasar and SQLite?

Comment: I got this to work in a Vite + Vue + Electron project. Perhaps this will help.